# What are copied pointers and how do they work?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am studying smart pointers and I have an Assignment where I have to implement a String Buffer class using copied Pointers, but i am not able to grasp the basic concept of what copied pointers are and how they work.

Comment: I have never heard of a copied pointer type.  Are you sure they did not want you to use a shared pointer?

Comment: Never heard the term "copied pointer". Of course you can copy a pointer and have another reference to your object. You can also copy the object your pointer is referencing. But what exactly are you supposed to do?

Comment: No its not shared pointer. 
@FrankPuffer Copied pointer will basically provide two copies of the object to both pointers. What i exactly need to do is that I need to implement a string class that performs std functions of std:string like length(), append(), chatAt() etc. using the copied pointer.

Comment: If you search for the term "deep copy", you will probably find lots of information.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Thank you. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wish Fahad Satti could have been more helpful, any ways here's something I found

http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/copied_ptr.h , I hope this helps.

Comment: I found it two days ago. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @IffatFatima did you find copied_ptr.cpp ? if yes, then do share it here.

Comment: @SEGrad2K13 No I didn't. I'm implementing my own class now.

Comment: Uhhh the implementation is in the header. There is no copied_ptr.cpp, it would have nothing in it.

Comment: @IffatFatima In copied pointers, deep copying occurs, right ?